# What is the purpose of an image in an Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

lets say If i had some production rule:

```
void NonTerminal() #NonTerminal: {}
{
    t = <TOKEN> {jjtThis.value = t.image};
}
```

What is the purpose of t.image here?

Comment: Hi, what us the purpose of t.image, I rephrased the question. @AndyTurner

Comment: From the JavaCC documentation (https://javacc.org/apiroutines): "**String image**: This represents the image of the token as it appeared in the input stream."

Answer (score 1):

Each `Token` object represents some sequence of characters that occurred in the input stream.  `t.image` is that sequence of characters as a `String` object.

The purpose of the code

```
{ jjtThis.value = t.image; }
```

is to store that `String` in the `.value` field of the node currently being built.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now! Thanks very much! @TheodoreNorvell